# How to visualize time frame ranges from string text type in tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

[I have tried changing the year ranges to a numeric type to get a visualization of how many years in business into a pie chart so that there is a slice for each range. I have tried using count as well but get error message. help pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Zad.png)

Comment: What's your desired output? Can you draw it on a piece of paper to explain? The string field cannot be converted to a numeric field but can certainly be used in a pie chart as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try just selecting the field 'Years in business' and `count(table name)` together and click on `pie chart` option on `show_me` (ctrl +1) tab.

You pie will be built automatically.

If you desire to divide the pie slices according to some other measure select that instead of count(table) alongwith `years in business` while clicking `pie chart` option on `show me`.